# Finding nearest station index on the grid from given data points in lat/lon on a grid in Python

Tags: python, gis, nearest-neighbor

I have 30000 data points on a grid and 4000 data points of stations of which, data is known. I need to find out which station index is closest to all the 30000 grid point. Please note that the locations of all the points are in lat/lon and I am writing the code in Python.

P.S.- I think, calculating the distance of a point from all the stations and then finding the minimum would not be feasible for 30000 points.

```py
# Pseudo-Code!    
station_location = a list of 4000 lat, long points
data_points = a list containing lat & long of 30000 grid points
```

**Required output**

```py
# Pseudo-Code!
for i in range(data_points):
   which station_location index is nearest to data_points[i]
```

Thanks

Comment: Your python code has a lot os syntax errors. Please fix your code

Comment: it wasnt a code, i just wrote it for better understanding

Comment: Ah, so could you then post the code of what you have tried?

Comment: what are these 30.000 data point exactly? Integers?